# How to profile for cache performance of an application that runs natively on Intel MIC architecture

Tags: intel, intel-mic

How to check if the given data for an application fits in L1 cache or L2 cache for applications that run natively on MIC. I have been searching for it for so much time as I have to try out various data that fits in L1 cache, L2 cache and neither of the caches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how much memory is used for the computation whether it is malloc or static assignment. Then check the size of the L1 cache. For L1 data cache on MIC, it is 32 KB.  From this, calculate the size of the data so that it can fit in L1 data cache. A similar approach can be taken for L2 cache as well. In MIC L2 cache is of size 512 KB.